# Numerical inaccuracy in computational verification of Gauss' law

Tags: electromagnetism, computational-physics, simulations, integration

We are verifying a computational method by comparing results to the theoretical results presented by Gauss' law for a uniformly distributed sphere of charge. Points are randomly selected inside the sphere with a uniform distribution and the individual contributions from each point are summed up to approximate the total electric field. However, the numerical results deviate significantly from the theoretical, which is that the field should be identical to the case where the entire sphere of charge is condensed into a single point.

I have placed a sensor at 4mm from the origin and I sample ten million random points inside a sphere centered at the origin of varying radii from 0 to 2.5mm. The results are summarized below.

```
Radius: Measured field
0.0000: 6.25
0.0001: 6.25073331456
0.0002: 6.25303831272
0.0003: 6.25692236761
0.0004: 6.26239802583
0.0005: 6.26971407158
0.0006: 6.27845566763
0.0007: 6.28885112861
0.0008: 6.3009353406
0.0009: 6.31474962706
0.0010: 6.33034222995
0.0011: 6.34776888923
0.0012: 6.3670935367
0.0013: 6.38838912412
0.0014: 6.41173861076
0.0015: 6.4372361424
0.0016: 6.46498846227
0.0017: 6.49511660603
0.0018: 6.52775794773
0.0019: 6.56306868384
0.0020: 6.6012268699
0.0021: 6.64243616132
0.0022: 6.68693046178
0.0023: 6.73497975576
0.0024: 6.78689750604
```

Of course, the case where the radius is 0 matches perfectly with the expected field. But as the sphere grows larger the measured field reaches 4% error of the expected value. I suspect that this has to do with the "random sampling" scheme which places points close to the sensor which causes an overall increase in detected field that is not quite balanced out by the decrease in overall density of points. Can this issue be solved? Moving the sensor farther away is not an option.

Comment: What is your sensor made from? Have you considered that your sensor might distort the charge distribution of the sphere so it is no longer uniform?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear: the "sensor" refers to where I take measurements from in my simulation, the point $r_0$ in $\sum_{samples}{\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0 (r_{sample}-r_0)^2}}$...

Comment: If this is all simulation, can you then clarify why moving the sensor away is not an option?

Comment: The purpose of the simulation is to investigate near-field behavior of different charge distributions. Thus, it is necessary (for starters) that there should at least be some semblance of accuracy for a basic distribution with the sensor at a (somewhat) close distance.

Comment: How are you doing the sampling?
If you are uniformly sampling $(r, \theta, \phi)$, then you are not getting a uniform density of points. (Points farther from the origin will be more spread out.) 
You should sample $(x, y, z)$ uniformly, and discard samples for which $(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) > R^2$.

Comment: Yes, the sampling is uniform in Cartesian space.